# OpenCV will not load a big image (~4GB)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, matplotlib, large-files

I'm working on a program that is to detect colored ground control points from a rather large image. The TIFF image is some 3 - 4 GB (aboud 35 000 x 33 000 pix).
I am using Python 2, and OpenCV to do the image processing.

```
import cv2
img = 'ortho.tif'
I = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

This part does not (always) produce an error message. While showing the image does:

```
cv2.imshow('image', I)
```

I have also tried showing the image by using matplotlib:

```
plt.imshow(I[:, :, ::-1])  # Hack to change BGR to RGB
```

Is there any limitation on OpenCV or Python regarding large images?
What would you suggest to get this iamge loaded?

PS: The computer I do this work on is a Windows 10 "workstation" (It has enough horsepowers to deal with the image).

In advance, thanks for your help :)

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: For matplotlib

    plt.imshow(self.image[:, :, ::-1])
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '\_\_getitem\_\_'

OpenCV sais:

    OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, file ..\..\..\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 261
    cv2.imshow('image', self.image)
    cv2.error: ..\..\..\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

Essentially, it sais that the image has size 0 x 0 pixels.

Comment: ...and you're positive that this stuff (and when I say this stuff I mean OpenCV and Python) has been compiled for 64 bits?

Comment: It was installed using anaconda from continuum using the 64 bit installer, so it should be compiled for 64 bit.

Additionally, when I run python, it sais it is the 64 bit version.

Comment: can you confirm that you can write a trivial C++ program that mallocs (35000*35000*3*sizeof(unsigned char)) and writes something to each location and that that program runs normally.

Comment: Yes, I created a numpy array of ones, having the size of 35 000 x 33 000 x 3, all of type integer.

Comment: I don't really know enough C++ to do much usefull.

Comment: PS: If I load a smaler image (approx. screen size), it works as it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implementation of [`imread()`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp):

```
Mat imread( const string& filename, int flags )
{
    Mat img;
    imread_( filename, flags, LOAD_MAT, &img );
    return img;
}
```

This allocates the matrix corresponding to load an image as a contiguous array. So this depends (at least partly) on your hardware performance: your machine must be able to allocate 4 GB contiguous RAM array (if you're on a Debian distro, you may check your RAM size by running, for example, [`vmstat -s -SM`](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Performance_Measurements_using_vmstat)).

By curiosity, I tried to get a contiguous memory array  (a big one, but **less** than the one your 4 GB image requires) using [`ascontiguousarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html#numpy.ascontiguousarray), but before that, I already stumbled on a memory allocation problem:

```
>>> img = numpy.zeros(shape=(35000,35000))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
>>>
```

In practice, even if you have enough RAM, it is not a good idea to manipulate the pixels of a 4 GB RAM image and you will need to split it anyway in terms of *[regions of interests](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html#image-roi)*, smaller areas and may be *[channels](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html#splitting-and-merging-image-channels)* too, depending on the nature of the operations you want to perform on the pixels.

**EDIT 1:**

As I said in my comment below your answer, if you have 16GB of RAM and you're able to read that image with [scikit](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.html) then there is no reason you can not do the same with OpenCV.

Please give this a try:

```
import numpy as np # Do not forget to import numpy
import cv2    
img = cv2.imread('ortho.tif')
```

You forgot to import Numpy in your original code and that is why OpenCV obviously failed to load the image.  All the OpenCV array structures are converted to-and-from Numpy arrays and the image you read  are represented by OpenCV as arrays in the memory.

**EDIT 2:**

OpenCV can deal with imaes which size is up to 10 GB. But this is true when it comes `cv2.imwrite()` function. For `cv2.imread()`, however, the size of the image to read is much smaller: that is a bug announced on September 2013 ([*Issue3258 #1438*](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/1438)) which is still, AFAIK, not fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. One of the goals of this program is to find the regions of interest automatically. Thus the entire image has to be in memory, though not neccesserily at the same time. I've hear of [`h5py`](http://www.h5py.org/) which is supposed to do something similar to your suggestion. I don't have any experience with this library though.

Comment: How much RAM does your machine have? @cLupus

Comment: The computer has 16 GB of RAM (DDR3).

Comment: Acually, I have tried with `import numpy as np`, but I get the same error.

Comment: That is really bizarre. Can you read a small sized picture with OpenCV without error/problem? @cLupus

Comment: I prefer you deaccept my answer as I do not have an explanation for this situation. @cLupus

Comment: Ok. Although, your answer and comments did lead me to a solution that worked, although not using OpenCV, which is not a must for this project.
Thanks for your time, and replies :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104793/discussion-between-begueradj-and-clupus).

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) came to the rescue, which I found out from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951507/out-of-core-4d-image-tif-storage-as-hdf5-python).

The following let me load the image into a python session:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imread

img = imread(path_to_file)
```

It took about half a minute, or so, to load.

Comment: It runs without an error, but the variable img is empty (np.size(img) gives output 1), while scikit's imread, gives an image with data (some 4 bilion bits).

Comment: I guess you did the right decision of not relying on OpenCV for this specific image:  I took time to look around because your problem intrigues me. Finally I found that is a **bug**. You may check the edit of my answer and ...accept it because that is the explanation of the problem you faced. It is, finally, a problem of the library itself, not the hardware or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Used this thread to no avail.... 
[Remove OpenCV image size limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963452/remove-opencv-image-size-limitation/61051598#61051598)
In summary, pip install tifffile and it will load tif files into numpy arrays which can then be used with OpenCV as per usual (but at your own risk with such large files.... OpenCV is designed with the assumption of an image less than 1 gigapixel)

Answer (score 0):

This likely is a limitation of the tiff library used.
One would need to use bigTIFF with 64bit tables.
Perhaps USE_WIN32_FILEIO=OFF helps when building openCV from source.
Also using a python package that uses a large tiff library helps.