# how can read big images on opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I need read a big image with openCV for processing a othomosaic. I using python for programming with openCV and it's a slice of my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

imageName = "map.tif"

imagem = cv2.imread(imageName)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(imagem, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

and this error happens:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F)) in cvtColor, file /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3959
```

But for other short maps i have success on processing.
I thinking this problem happened because the function cv2.imread doesn't have memory to read a big image, but i don't know any solution for this, someone have any idea?

Comment: The error is stating that the number of colour channels is neither 3 or 4, and that the type is not 8-bit int or 32-bit float, it states nothing about image size

Comment: After reading the image from file, run `print(imagem.shape)`. Post results here.

Comment: cv2.error: /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:269: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow

Comment: maybe the imread doesn't works

Comment: with the print(imagem), the results were "None"

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: my OS is Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I think this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35666761/opencv-will-not-load-a-big-image-4gb can help