# Dask's imread returns MemoryError - change chunk sizes on import

Tags: python, arrays, tiff, dask

I have a series of *.tiff movies that are too large for numpy to deal with `(shape = (1, 9000, 512, 512))` and it seems like `dask.array.image.imread`  could handle this (according to the answer of this question: [out of core 4D image tif storage as hdf5 python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951507/out-of-core-4d-image-tif-storage-as-hdf5-python/)).

When creating the array, `dask.array.image.imread` gives a MemoryError when trying to import any of the large files. It does, however, work on smaller stacks of files with `shape = (1, 20, 512, 512)`, so I think it must be something about chunk sizes. I've tried to see if I can change the chunk size upon import within imread but I haven't found anything.

When dask's own `imread` didn't work, I tried the [`dask_imread` package](http://dask-imread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dask_imread.html), which seemed to have the ability to split frames into chunks. Interestingly, it gives me a RuntimeWarning when creating the array, but upon `print(foo_array)` still returns

```
dask.array<from-value, shape=(1, 9000, 512, 512), dtype=uint16, chunksize=(1, 9000, 512, 512)>
```

With a chunksize of the **entire file.**
Trying `.rechunk((1,20,512,512))`  returns

```
dask.array<rechunk-merge, shape=(1, 9000, 512, 512), dtype=uint16, chunksize=(1, 20, 512, 512)>
```

as expected.

However, when running `.compute()` on any element of the array, for example `print(foo_array[0,1234,123,123].compute())` gives a MemoryError.
I've tried importing as `foo_array = imread(file_to_use,chunksize=(1,20,512,512))` but it seems that neither`imread` takes `chunksize` as a kwarg.

How do I change the chunksize upon import in `imread` to for example (1,20,512,512) (which seems to be manageable)?

Comment: Hi Magnus, I'm the author of `dask-imread`. Currently it is setup to treat the 0th axis as the frame number. Though we could explore other ways of cutting up the file into frames (even over multiple axes) if you would like. Please feel free to raise an issue on the repo and we can discuss more. Thanks for giving `dask-imread` a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `dask.array.imread` works better with stacks of many small images than with individual large ones.  If you know how to read only a slice out of a large image then I recommend creating your own data reading function with `dask.delayed` and `dask.array.from_delayed`.  This blogpost may provide a decent example: http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/01/17/dask-images